# Distributing ruby gems in a C/C++ GNU autotools project

Tags: c++, ruby, rubygems, autotools, polyglot

I am working in a polyglot project which mostly uses C++ and for some high level tasks Ruby.

In my Ruby scripts I extensively used few very useful gems. However, although my Autotools setup is installing the ruby scripts, I do not find any way to distribute the required gems.

Do you know any idiom or way to deal with this issue?